# How to multi level sort an array in excel, using formulas? I am aware about the way, using SORT button on DATA tab

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

Input data:

| r1 | r2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

Output data:

| r1 | r2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |

Using SORT formula in excel, gives the result:

| r1 | r2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

Comment: The thing is that Excel's sort function in all flavors (Sort button in the Data tab, `SORT`, `SORTBY`) performs a so-called stable sort i.e. the remaining columns keep their vertical positions. This is the preferred (best) way. You actually want to sort both columns hence you need to sort twice: first the 2nd column and then the 1st. The answer presented by Jos Woolley shows how it is done by using formulas where it is most important to keep in mind that the last column to be sorted comes first. The same goes for `Custom Sort` in the Data tab: first (Level1) is column r1 then comes column r2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SORTBY`, e.g.

`=SORTBY(A2:B5,A2:A5,1,B2:B5,1)`

or simply `SORT` with an appropriate second parameter:

`=SORT(A2:B5,SEQUENCE(,2))`

Comment: Is there a reason behind the comma in the SEQUENCE function? I know what it does but it also works without it.

Comment: I was omitting the *rows* parameter and instead entering the value 2 as the *columns* parameter, as that seemed the right choice, though you're correct that it doesn't appear to make a difference.

Comment: Sir, your solution using `SORT()` & `SEQUENCE()` sorted one of my own problems. Thanks =)

Comment: Thx for checking and clarifying. I must agree. Hardly related, just for the sake of sharing a thought, why it could be good that it works both ways is that we mostly have the semi-colon (`;`) as the row separator (correct me if I'm wrong) but we have different column separators e.g. the default (US) `,`, `.`, \ (mine)... so when using a hard-coded array instead of the SEQUENCE function, it might be preferable to use the row separator (;) to make formulas work with fewer necessary changes. And another one, If you would want column `B` sorted descending, you could add `SEQUENCE(,2,1,-2)`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Absolutely agree. And for cases in which it is necessary to employ a horizontal array the `SEQUENCE` function comes in very useful, as you don't have to worry about such translation issues. I often post formulas with `SEQUENCE(,2)` in place of `{1,2}` these days for that reason.